# How to set same width for pictures in Lightbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox

On my website, some pictures are pretty long (width varies between 400 and 1000px while height >= 3500px). I want to **set same width (800px) for all pictures** in Lightbox and then scroll down to view them, but don't know how. **Where and what exactly should I change in the lightbox.css or lightbox.js?**

Comment: try in `lightbox.css` change **`.lb-outerContainer to  width: 800px !important;`** and add **`.lb-container: max-width: 800px`**

Comment: Thank you, but it's not successful. Actually I had tried it before I posted this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved**

My Lightbox version is v2.9.0 by Lokesh Dhakar. I solved the problem by commenting out the image fitting part in the lightbox.js. Specifically, in lightbox.js, comment out lines 276-281 and 290-321. This operation will prevent an image from resizing to fit the window and will allow users to scroll down to view a picture if the picture's height exceeds the height of the window.